# Listar en un combobox los elementos de dos columnas distintas

Tags: java, sql

Estoy tratando realizar lo siguiente con Java y Oracle PLSQL.

En la base de datos se disponibilizaran dos emails de una persona, uno sera propio del sistema y el otro sera de un sistema externo.
Existira un momento donde debo escoger uno de los emails mediante sistema el cual estoy planeando listar en un combobox. El problema surge puesto que los mails se encuentran en la DB un mismo registro pero en columnas distintas, estilo EMAIL | EMAIL_SECUNDARIO, por tanto no estan en una tabla de tipo relacional donde le pueda asignar un codigo, mail para asi listarlos en el combo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo aparte es una tabla que clasifica los tipos de email mediante codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien puedo relacionar las tablas clasificando el tipo de email mediante un JOIN entre TIPO_EMAIL y COD_EMAIL, esto no veo que me sirva para poder listar realmente ambos mail en un combobox.

Mi idea es que al desplegar el combo diga algo como.

1. Email1
2. Email2

Como podria lograr eso?.

Muchas gracias.
Saludos!

Comment: entonces... esto no es un problema de java, es de sql puro? el motor en este caso podria no importar, pero mejor aclararlo en la etiqueta.. y otra cosa, todas las filas tienen los dos mails, o es uno o el otro? y obviamente, si se puede, lo ideal es arreglar esa db ya...

Comment: Claro mas que nada necesitaria ordenar lo que es SQL. Todas las filas tendran solo 2 emails, uno principal, uno secundario y un campo indicando el tipo de mail, el cual se relacionara con otra tabla que tendra codigo y descripcion.
Mi idea es listar ambos emails en un combo para que se pueda escojer, y al escojer uno, actualize el campo TIPO_EMAIL por el tipo de mail escogido, si el 1 o el 2.

Comment: Un campo que indica el tipo de email.. para el principal o el secundario? O para los dos? Y vos queres mostrar los mails o los tipos de email?

Comment: Mi idea es la siguiente:
Listar en un combo para escoger el mail 1 y mail 2.
Al momento de escoger el mail y grabar, tomar ese mail y escribirlo en el campo mail1, mientras que el sobrante ponerlo en el mail 2 y a la vez, en el campo tipo_email, anotar cual de los dos mails quedo como vigente en mail1 (si es el principal 1 o es el secundario 2).

Por que haria esto?
Lo pense asi por que el sistema usa el campo mail1 en varios lados y no quiero alterar la logica, entonces la idea es solo reemplazar el nuevo a ese campo y dejar anotado si corresponde al mail sistemico o externo.

Comment: ok.. y en el combo se listan los email de todos o de un usuario en particular... Igual tendria que estar normalizado esto.. eso te quedo claro no?

Comment: Tengo unas dudas:
1- ¿Cómo es la estructura de la tabla?. Ayudaría saber si los campos de email pueden contener NULL.
2- ¿tipo_email puede tener el valor 2 aunque exista valor en e_mail?

Comment: gbianchi, efectivamente se listan los mail de un usuario en particular, la cual su data esta en el mismo registro.

Damian Alva, los campos de email si puede contener null ya que es posible que el usuario no tenga un mail de sistema o un mail externo, es decir que tenga solo uno.
El tipo_email no deberia tener valor 2 si es que no existe un mail en EMAIL_SECUNDARIO.
El unico caso de que podria tener valor 2, es que en algun momento haya tenido 2 mails y se haya quitado el principal quedando vigente solo el EMAIL_SECUNDARIO

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo este "truquito" en la tabla tienes por ej los campos email1, email2 que son los que mostrarás en el combo pero ambos concatenados. Ahora bien crea un tercer campo llamado emailsConcatenados, cuando vayas a salvar la información de los emails pues inserta en el nuevo campo la concatenación de email1 y 2 separados por algún separador ej email1/email2 y ese campo sería el que mostraría por tu combo.
Lo otro que podrías hacer es sobrescribir el combo pero esto ya es algo más complicadito

Comment: Muchas gracias Japv. Entiendo la solucion que indicas, pero mi duda si aplico esa solucion es: ¿Como hago para que en el combo pueda escoger y en base a eso realizar otra accion?, pues imagino que los mails concatenados EMAIL1/EMAIL2 serian un solo texto.

Comment: por dios.. en serio? romper la base de datos mas rota de lo que esta? tene en cuenta que esta "solucion" va a ser un problema, cuando por ejemplo hayan escrito mal el email2, y tengas que cambiarlo en ese campo... o tengas 3 o 4 emails...

Comment: bueno @gbianchi, yo propongo una solución que podría servir en determinados casos, pero la normalización de la bd no va por mi, va por el usuario, todo depende de donde puede aplicarse

Comment: Claro.. pero como se supone que en un campo, con dos datos pegados que estan en otro campo, vas a sacar 2 items distintos de un combo???

Comment: No es necesario desnormalizar la tabla más de lo que está. Lo que dice @gbianchi es cierto, va a traer problemas a futuro.

Hay que considerar la opción de realizarlo en una sola consulta. Tal vez con UNION.

Comment: @gbianchi, como dije todo depende del problema que se quiera resolver, por ejemplo en Delphi, Foxpro puedes enlazar el combo a n campos a través de la propiedad displaymember(no recuerdo exactamente como se llama), aquí lamentablemente no es de esta forma, solo es un campo

Answer (score 0):

Como solo queres dos valores de un solo registro en tu combo, entonces tu query deberia ser asi:

```
select e_mail 
from tabla
where id = ?
union
select e_mail_secundario
from tabla
where id = ?
```

con eso, vas a tener los dos emails uno abajo del otro..

Lo que estamos haciendo ahi, es tomar uno de los campos, armar un resultado con eso, y unirlo a otro resultado que tiene el otro campo.

Comment: Hola gbianchi, exacto, buscando por ahi di con la misma solucion, y funciona, me deja ambos mails en un solo listado.
El problema me surge ahora respecto a identificar cual es cual, o sea, darle una especie de codigo.
Cuando realizo la consulta en SQL retorno una collection donde segun estructura del combo deberia retornar algo como


     
          cor.setCodigo ( Correos.getString(1) );
          cor.setEmail ( Correos.getString(2) );

Me quedaria crear una tabla unica de mails, pero eso complica la logica inicial, pues tendria q hacer un volcado de mails a la nueva tabla.

Comment: Eso te lo dije en un comentario ayer no? Que no entendia como esperabas saber cual era cual?

Comment: Lo que hice fue crear 2 campos mas en la tabla: Campo tipo_mail_sistema y tipo_mail_secundario, todo esto para mantenerlos fijos con el numero 1 y 2 respectivamente y asi poder hacer un select union por separado de modo de listar ambos mails con sus respectivos codigos segun usuario, lo cual funciono:

        'select tipo_mail_sistema as COD_MAIL, e_mail AS EMAIL from USUARIOS where ID= 19136     
        union all
        select tipo_mail_afp AS COD_MAIL, e_mail_secundario AS EMAIL from usuarios where ID= 19136 
        ORDER BY cod_mail;'

Comment: El problema que me ocurre ahora es que si bien consultando en el motor de la base de datos funciona bien, al traerlos al combo quedan con los codigos invertidos.

Es decir:

Si en el motor de ORACLE me trae:

1 - sistema@gmail.com
2 - afp@gmail.com

En la lista de retorno a JAVA me trae siempre 

1 - sistema@gmail.com
2 - afp@gmail.com

Independiente si en la tabla los doy vuelta de casilla como para dejar a sistema como 2 y afp como 1.

No entiendo que podria estar pasando ahi :/.

Comment: Y si en lugar de seguir rompiendo cada vez mas la tabla, la arreglas normalizandola como corresponde? No entiendo esa necesidad de crear todavia mas campos, cuando con una tabla secundaria solucionas todos los problemas....

Comment: Entiendo lo que sugieres, el problema de generar una tabla secundaria es que tendria que hacer un volcado de todos los mails de la primera tabla segun usuario, y el otro tema es que todo el sistema rescata el mail desde la primera tabla en sus modulos, es por ello que estoy viendo como listar ambos mails y al momento de que alguno sea escogido, ese mail sea actualizado en el campo MAIL original, mientras que el mail que queda, quede grabado en mail secundario.

Comment: El volcado seria trivial. Lo otro es un poquito mas complejo pq tendrias que arreglar tu sistema, y en lugar de leer de ese campo leer de la nueva tabla. Ahora, un mal diseño te esta complicando de sobremanera la vida... y si dejas en esa tabla solo el email primario y mandas todos los secundarios a otra tabla? Es un parche horrible.